# Google In-App purchase token format issue

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

The regular Google purchase token format looks like this:

> minodojglppganfbiedlabed.AO-J1OyNtpooSraUdtKlZ_9gYs0o20ZF_0ryTNACmvaaaG5EwPX0hPruUdGbE3XejoXYCYzJA2xjjAxrDLFhmu9WC4fvTDNL-RDXCWjlHKpzLOigxCr1QhScXR8uXtX8R94iV6MmMHqD

Now I got a weird token looks like this:

```
nmdwkbdkikkamkahxjnsnshb
```

which obviously came from a hacking tool. However, it becomes much weird because when you attach the suspicious token to the prefix of the valid token:

> **nmdwkbdkikkamkahxjnsnshb**.AO-J1OyNtpooSraUdtKlZ_9gYs0o20ZF_0ryTNACmvaaaG5EwPX0hPruUdGbE3XejoXYCYzJA2xjjAxrDLFhmu9WC4fvTDNL-RDXCWjlHKpzLOigxCr1QhScXR8uXtX8R94iV6MmMHqD

The token becomes valid. It should have been invalid since the whole token did not exist or am I wrong? Does anybody experience this? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting find, your question had my curiosity so I did some digging. I had a suspicion that the prefix looks just like the the *Order number* you get in the email receipt from Google, so I cross checked and bingo, they are:

[image: Google play email receipt]

Purchase Token: `gaaiealkdndcconacjhcmpcf.AO-J1OzF_av9Nl1ViLxR7u7vRlw7OXq32n35GkOEhrMbAfm3VV4g14IWgOg9kxFmJEF58MstHTEGRKKbS9oIPOkEy-EGzcAaItkR3P8_l7DP-6OCZVZAPO4`

The order number changes each time a subscription is renewed, and sending to the API any of the order numbers I have in my email receipts with the suffix attached validates as expected. I also tried some random 24 character alpha strings and they also worked so Google must not care too much about the prefix; it's only the suffix they are interested in.

Comment: Marc Greenstock -- Thank you so much for the reply and it make sense because I tried some random suffix and they did not accept it. Thanks again. :)